Redirect non-www and http to https://www.domainName
I am trying to force redirect in the .htaccess but it only works partially.
When I enter http://domainName or domainName, it redirects to https://www.domainName/ as expected
However, if I enter http://domainName/commercial for example, it redirects to https://domainName/commercial instead of https://www.domainName/commercial
I tried different methods of the redirect rules, but all produces the same result:
Option 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainName$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domainName/$1 [R=301,L]

Option 2
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Option 3 (swapped the order of option 2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Expected: https://www.domainName/commercial
But Getting: https://domainName/comercial

you might be experiencing browser level cache ! You can check redirections using https://httpstatus.io

I cleared the cache every time before testing. Also tried on other browsers.
I tried the site you suggested but I'm getting the same results with result - 200 (ok)

I tested again with the site you suggested, and I got 3 redirects which is matching the rules + one final URL which is the correct one. I guess it is working?

yes it should be.

great thank you. Still getting the same results on some browsers. Weird.

Can you try combine the rules and try once as told in this solution How to redirect HTTPS non-www to HTTPS www using .htaccess? And make sure to clear browser cache
